# Django: Parent Model with multiple child model types

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I've created a set of Django model for a CMS to show a series of `Product`s.

Each page contains a series of rows, so I have a generic

```
class ProductRow(models.Model):
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False, blank=False)
```

then I have a series of children of this model, for different types of row:

```
class ProductBanner(ProductRow):
  wide_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/banners/', max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
  top_heading_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
  main_heading_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
  ...

class ProductMagazineRow(ProductRow):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
  show_descriptions = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
  panel_1_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  panel_2_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  panel_3_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  ...

class ProductTextGridRow(ProductRow):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
  col1_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
  col1_product_1 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  col1_product_2 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  col1_product_3 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  ...
```

and so on.

Then in my `ProductPage` I have a series of `ProductRow`s:

```
class ProductPage(models.Model):
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
  row_1 = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow, related_name='+', null=False, blank=False)
  row_2 = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
  row_3 = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
  row_4 = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
  row_5 = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
```

The problem I have got, is that I want to allow those 5 rows in the `ProductPage` to be any of the different child types of `ProductRow`. However when I iterate over them such as

in `views.py`:

```
product_page_rows = [product_page.row_1,product_page.row_2,product_page.row_3,product_page.row_4,product_page.row_5]
```

and then in the template:

```
{% for row in product_page_rows %}
  <pre>{{ row.XXXX }}</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

I cannot reference any child field as `XXXX`.

I tried adding a "`type`()" method to both the parent and children, to try and distinguish which class each row is:

```
class ProductRow(models.Model):

  ...

  @classmethod
  def type(cls):
      return "generic"
```

and

```
class ProductTextGridRow(TourRow):

  ...

  @classmethod
  def type(cls):
      return "text-grid"
```

but if i change `XXXX` for `.type()` in the template then it shows `"generic"` for every item in the list (I had defined a variety of row types in the data), so I guess everything is coming back as a `ProductRow` rather than the appropriate child type. I can find no way to get the children to be accessible as the correct child type rather than the parent type, or to determine which child type they actually are (I tried `catch`ing `AttributeError` as well, that didn't help).

Can someone advise how I can properly handle a list of varied model types all of which contain a common parent, and be able to access the fields of the appropriate child model type?

Comment: Something looks wrong here... Are you sure you want multiple `ForeignKey`s inside all those models? Each `ForeignKey` represents a `1-N`  relationship, so, for example, your model `ProductRow` has 5 different relationships representing different things with `ProductPage`. Just confirming if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, each product page will have 5 different rows, each of which will be one of the various ProductRow types

Comment: .. and each product row might be used on multiple different pages

Comment: if it makes it simpler, consider a more standard object oriented example: I want to store a list of `Vehicle`s. Each `Vehicle` can be a `Car` or a `Bike` or a `Van` or a `Boat`. The `VehiclePage` contains a list of 5 `Vehicles` each of which can be a `Car` or a `Bike` or a `Van` or a `Boat`. I need to be able to cycle through the `Vehicle`s and say something like "if it's a `Car`, get its licence plate.... if it's a `Van`, get its cubic storage capacity, etc....`"

Comment: all I can say is you need to do your database design from scratch after reading up a bit more on database normalization, design etc

Comment: I know about normalization. I've deliberately chosen a denormalized approach here for reasons i don't want to get into. I think normalization or not is somewhat tangential to my question....

Answer (score 8):

This is generally (read "always") a bad design to have something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    row_1 = models.ForeignKey(...)
    row_2 = models.ForeignKey(...)
    row_3 = models.ForeignKey(...)
    row_4 = models.ForeignKey(...)
    row_5 = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

It is not scalable. If ever you want to allow 6 rows or 4 rows instead of 5, one day (who knows?), you will have to add/delete a new row and alter your database scheme (and handle existing objects that had 5 rows). And it's not DRY, your amount of code depends on the number of rows you handle and it involves a lot of copy-pasting.

This become clear that it is a bad design if you wonder how you would do it if you had to handle 100 rows instead of 5.

You have to use a [`ManyToManyField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) and some custom logic to ensure there is at least one row, and at most five rows.

```
class ProductPage(models.Model):
    ...
    rows = models.ManyToManyField(ProductRow)
```

If you want your rows to be ordered, you can use an explicit intermediate model like this:

```
class ProductPageRow(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'page'

    row = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow)
    page = models.ForeignKey(ProductPage)

class ProductPage(models.Model):
    ...
    rows = model.ManyToManyField(ProductRow, through=ProductPageRow)
```

I want to allow only `N` rows (let's say 5), you could implement your own `order_with_respect_to` logic:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class ProductPageRow(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('row', 'page', 'ordering')

    MAX_ROWS = 5

    row = models.ForeignKey(ProductRow)
    page = models.ForeignKey(ProductPage)
    ordering = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(MAX_ROWS - 1),
        ],
    )
```

The tuple `('row', 'page', 'ordering')` uniqueness being enforced, and ordering being limited to five values (from 0 to 4), there can't be more than 5 occurrences of the couple `('row', 'page')`.

**However,** unless you have a very good reason to make 100% sure that there is no way to add more than `N` rows in the database by any mean (including direct SQL query input on your DBMS console), there is no need to "lock" it a this level.

It is very likely that all "untrusted" user will only be able to update your database through HTML form inputs. And you can use **[formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/)** to force both a minimum and a maximum number of rows when filling a form.

> **Note:** This also applies to your other models. Any bunch of fields named
>   `foobar_N`, where `N` is an incrementing integer, betrays a very bad
>   database design.

---

Yet, this does not fix your issue.

The easiest (read "the first that comes to mind") way to get your child model instance back from the parent model instance is to loop over each possible child model until you get an instance that matches.

```
class ProductRow(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_actual_instance(self):
        if type(self) != ProductRow:
            # If it's not a ProductRow, its a child
            return self
        attr_name = '{}_ptr'.format(ProductRow._meta.model_name)
        for possible_class in self.__subclasses__():
            field_name = possible_class._meta.get_field(attr_name).related_query_name()
            try:
                return getattr(self, field_name)
            except possible_class.DoesNotExist:
                pass
         # If no child found, it was a ProductRow
         return self
```

**But** it involves to hit the database for each try. And it is still not very DRY. The most efficient way to get it is to add a field that will tell you the type of the child:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class ProductRow(models.Model):
    ...
    actual_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            self.actual_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))
         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_actual_instance(self):
        my_info = (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name)
        actual_info = (self.actual_type.app_label, self.actual_type.model)
        if type(self) != ProductRow or my_info == actual_info:
            # If this is already the actual instance
            return self
        # Otherwise
        attr_name = '{}_ptr_id'.format(ProductRow._meta.model_name)
        return self.actual_type.get_object_for_this_type(**{
            attr_name: self.pk,
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a good explanation of database normalization and link tables. As it happens I have some very specific reasons for preferring a fixed, finite number of denormalized fields in this case.

Thanks for the `self.actual_type` solution. That's very clever and exactly what I was trying to achieve!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `type()` method doesn't work because you're using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance): each of `ProductRow`'s children is a separate model connected to `ProductRow` using an automatically generated [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

- If you ensure that each `ProductRow` instance has only one type of child (out of the three possible ones), there is a simple way to find out whether that child is a `ProductBanner`, a `ProductMagazineRow` or a `ProductTextGridRow`, and then to use the appropriate fields:

  ```
  class ProductRow(models.Model):
      ...
      def get_type(self):
          try:
              self.productbanner
              return 'product-banner'
          except ProductBanner.DoesNotExist:
              pass

          try:
              self.productmagazinerow
              return 'product-magazine'
          except ProductMagazineRow.DoesNotExist:
              pass

          try:
              self.producttextgridrow
              return 'product-text-grid'
          except ProductTextGridRow.DoesNotExist:
              pass

          return 'generic'
  ```
- However, if you don't enforce otherwise, then one instance of `ProductRow` can be linked to more than one of `ProductBanner`, `ProductMagazineRow` and `ProductTextGridRow` at the same time. You'll have to work with the specific instances instead:

  ```
  class ProductRow(models.Model):
      ...
      def get_productbanner(self):
          try:
              return self.productbanner
          except ProductBanner.DoesNotExist:
              return None

      def get_productmagazinerow(self):
          try:
              return self.productmagazinerow
          except ProductMagazineRow.DoesNotExist:
              return None

      def get_producttextgridrow(self)
          try:
              return self.producttextgridrow
          except ProductTextGridRow.DoesNotExist:
              return None
  ```

Combine this with with Antonio Pinsard's answer to improve your database design.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the child types overlap"? The relation from the children is a one-to-one, it is not possible for a parent to have more than one child.

Comment: A little clarity: a 'parent' instance of `ProductRow` can have one 'child' each, namely instances of `ProductBanner`, `ProductMagazineRow` and `ProductTextGridRow`. I'll change the language of the second point to include this

Comment: Thanks @YashTewari. When you `try` `self.productmagazinerow` and similar, I assume those are just fields that are unique to a given child type? so essentially the approach is.. try to access a field that is unique to a certain child type... then catch the error if it doesn't exist. I like it, clever.

Comment: PS The database design is deliberately denormalized, I have specific reasons for having chosen a fixed, finite number of fields in this case.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if `self.productmagazinerow` is a field unique to the model `ProductMagazineRow`. No, `self.productmagazinerow` is an automatically created field in `ProductRow`. It is created when you derive the model  `ProductMagazineRow` from `ProductRow`. Refer to the top of my answer, and follow the link to [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)